# WebStorm project dir as Resource Root dir for local server

Tags: webstorm

In my case Project structure looks like:

```
/Users/myuser/WebstormProjects/project1
/Users/myuser/WebstormProjects/project1/index.html
/Users/myuser/WebstormProjects/project1/img/someimg.png
```

When I click on browser icon in top right cornet to open html file in browser

[image: open with internal server]

I get in my loca browser URL like this:

```
http://localhost:63342/project1/index.html?_ijt=jfpl6u1husnai9t2635bb0gffs
```

For deployment I use in index.html absolute paths to my resources like images etc, for example,

```
<img src="/img/someimg.png">
```

I get broken images paths. For this case when in html code `src="/img/someimg.png"` browser with local server see it as `src="http://localhost:63342/img/someimg.png"` but root folder URL in this case is must be `http://localhost:63342/project1/`.

PS. Attempt to mark project1 - Resource Root don't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Leading slashes in resource URL tell the browser to resolve URLs from the web server root. Internal web server returns 404 when using 'absolute' URLs as it serves files from `localhost:port/project_name` and not from `localhost:port` - it's a simple web server that only serves files from the project root folder and doesn't have any advanced routing/doc root configurations. If you like your URLs to be resolved when hosting your app on the built-in web server, use URLs relative to current file (`<img src="path/relative/to/index.html"`)

If altering URLs is not an option, you a different web server to host your files

Comment: I only use absolute paths to resources from server webroot, I think this is a good tone in html. It strange why WebStorm cant reconfigure webroot like i can do tit with php webserver `php -S localhost:8000 -t /Users/myuser/WebstormProjects/project1` ?!! It simple in php but no solution for WebStorm!